# Using Apps Script to return to certain cell and make it editable-ready in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm quite new to Apps Script. I hope someone could help me please.

I wanted to create an Apps Script in Google Sheet where the script will return to cell C4 and make it editable-ready. My script is as below:-

`function EditC4() {`
`var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`
`spreadsheet.getRange('C4').activate();`
`}`

Problem with this script is that just made C4 active but it is un-editable. Pressing F2 when the C4 is being made 'active' does not work as well. I'm calling the EditC4 function from another function.
I prefer not to use "Browser.msgBox" to make it edit-ready. Could someone please help? I search everywhere but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

The [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#activate) method is used mainly by macros to register some cells or ranges as active and then use [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getActiveRange()) or [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getActiveRange()) to get these ranges back.

- In your case, you want to "highlight" or "mark" a particular cell so it can be edited directly with the keyboard.

In this case you want to use [activateAsCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#activateAsCurrentCell()) .

- Also it is a better practice to get the [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en) object from the [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object and not directly from the [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) object.

### Solution:

```
function EditC4() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
   sheet.getRange('C4').activateAsCurrentCell();
}
```

### Illustration:

[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried it out. It still doesn't work. I tried recording macro with the steps and F2, ,and call it from another Function. Doesn't work as well.

Comment: @May how did you run the code? Provide more details because I can't reproduce your issue.. I added a gif to illustrate how I run it to see how it works. If you want to execute this function in a different way, then provide more details.

Comment: There is a button called "Clear". The user will click the button Clear after filling in the details. So, after the user click the Clear button, the active cell will go back to C4 and the user could immediately start keying in the next record.
However,  what happen is that, after I click Clear button, the cell went back to C4, but I can't type in anything immediately. I have to use the mouse to click back at C4, before I can enter in text. I would like to avoid using the mouse to click at C4. Is this possible? If could, I would like to have everything done through the keyboard. 
This form

Comment: This form is meant for fast data entry. Thus, I'm trying to save the movement for the user to reach out to the mouse and click at C4 to do data entry.

Comment: @May I see your issue. I think this is an intended behavior or a bug which can not be solved via script. I think the reason for that is the message that pop ups when the script is running. You need to escape this message before you type something in the cell. The workaround is to press `ESC` and then you will be able to add something in the cell. Can you confirm if that works? I would suggest you to file a report in the [issueTrack](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) regarding that.

Comment: Hi @Marios. You are right. I do have to press Esc, followed by F2 before I can edit the cell. This is close enough and good enough. Thank you very much for your advice.